# GridView Scroll up and Scrolldown

Tags: android, gridview

I have this code that when you scroll down or up the gridview it will hide the top container. my problem is that it will just execute when it was scrolled up or down then release.

how do I hide my top container if the user scrolls down without releasing it.?

something like [Scrolling tricks](https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/1Sb549FvpJt)

mygrid.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

```
      @Override
      public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final GridView lw = (GridView) view;

        if (view.getId() == lw.getId()) {
          final int currentFirstVisibleItem = lw.getFirstVisiblePosition();

          if (currentFirstVisibleItem > mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
            mTopContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //Scroll down
          } else if (currentFirstVisibleItem < mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
            mTopContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //Scroll Up 
          }

          mLastFirstVisibleItem = currentFirstVisibleItem;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your scroll logic into the onScroll method of the OnScrollListener:

```
    public abstract void onScroll (AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        //in this method also some parameters are automatically passed, so you don't have to get them from the GridView
    }
```